# Is using a strained metaphor bad style, when would it be justified?

Tags: creative-writing, metaphor

Found across some resource talking about strained metaphor:

> Strained Metaphor
>
> A metaphor becomes strained, when the comparison becomes far fetched,
> or when the figure is dragged into irrelevant details. Such a strained
> metaphor tends to become obscure.
>
> The following passage from Shakespeare’s Macbeth may be taken as an
> example of the strained metaphor :
>
> ```
> “Here lay Duncan,
>
> His silver skin laced with his golden blood.”
> ```
>
> Here the comparison between gold and blood is far-fetched.

Is using a strained metaphor bad style, when would it be justified?

Comment: I'd be hard-pressed to accuse Shakespeare of bad style. Also notice it is MacBeth that's using the metaphor, it's part of his dialogue.

Comment: Can you explain how that line is 'strained'...? I see only 1 metaphor: a dead king and precious metals. What is 'strained' about it?

Comment: A strained metaphor is by definition bad, because the definition of a strained metaphor is one that is overextended to the point of being confusing or ridiculous.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the resource you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a strained metaphor.

The dead body of most any Scots will be grey, because the blood settles in the back. Silver is grayish. And, Duncan was of royal descent, and gold is the color of royalty

Strained metaphors are appropriate when the author wants to show that the character is a pompous twit, and/or incredibly ignorant — either through dialogue or thought.

Lots of metaphors, strained or otherwise, are usually an indicator of bad writing, in most cases.  But, there maybe times when it is very much to the right thing to write.